# MVC3 Modal form inside a different page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I apologize in advance if this is confusing, it's difficult for me to put this concept into words.

Let's say I have a`Payment` Create screen, with a dropdown or listbox to select the associated `Vendor`, where exactly one `Vendor` must be chosen... but the `Vendor` does not yet exist.  I don't want to redirect the user to another page so they can create the prerequisite `Vendor`, and have the user lose all the information he/ she has already put in.  Instead I'd like to put a link on the screen that, when clicked, a modal form comes up so they can add the `Vendor` object on the fly, validate it, and reference it, then continue on with adding the `Payment` record.

I already have a Create screen for the `Vendor`, it would be ideal if I could somehow reuse that code, but I don't see an easy way to do that.

Here's another trick: the `Vendor` record may also reference something that does not exist; the possibility that there might be "nested" modal forms is reasonably high.  Additionally, there may be several "dependencies" for any given record, and I would want each one to exhibit the same sort of behavior for a consistent user experience.

Is there some mechanism in the MVC framework, or a decently established pattern for creating this behavior?  I'm trying for a contiguous, intuitive user experience and I'm scratching my head about the best way to do this.

Comment: Instead of modal windows you can go for child windows.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but it seems disruptive to the user experience, and then they have 2 windows open which can get confusing.  I'm hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is **Partial Views**.  They can be pretty much an entire page on their own, and you just plug them in wherever you want.

You include them in a page like so:

```
@Html.Partial("_PaymentScreen")
```

or if you need to render images or media at the same time as the original page load you can use this:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_PaymentScreen")
```

[These are all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.partialextensions.partial.aspx) your options for rendering a partial view, it's extremely versatile.

For your modal, you could do somthing like this:

```
<div id="myModal">
    @Html.RenderPartial("_PaymentScreen")
</div>
```

There are many resources on how to use them, here are a few:

- http://coding-in.net/mvc-3-organize-your-partial-views/
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/aravindbenator/mvc-3-razor-and-partial-view/
- http://geekswithblogs.net/blachniet/archive/2011/08/03/updating-partial-views-with-unobtrusive-ajax-in-mvc-3.aspx

Comment: I am familiar with partial views; in my experience these do not seem to be appropriate for what I am trying to do, for several reasons.  The models would not mesh, it would force me to nest `n` layers of model data, validation would become a nightmare.  The "Add New Vendor" link would definitely need to be an AJAX call, not in the original DOM.

Comment: Not sure why nesting a few layers of model data is that bad, I know you said `n` but your scenario only needs 2-3.  I'm not sure why validation would be a nightmare either, you are going to need AJAX for what you're doing so validation can just be done during posts to the controller actions.  If you want to try something different, look at a client side implementation.  Something like [Knockout JS](http://knockoutjs.com/).